# if a thousand is right

Tags: grammar, word-choice

Could I say:

- a thousand ten (1010),
- a thousand a hundred eleven(1111)

or in these cases I must use **one thousand** instead of **a thousand**? Would using "a" be grammatically incorrect?

Answer (score 3):

Br Eng would be

> One thousand and ten
>   One thousand, one hundred and eleven

US Eng seems to miss out the 'and' a lot of the time, but I've never figured the exact pattern, or if it's dialectical, but I've heard such as

> One thousand ten
>   One thousand, one hundred eleven

but I wouldn't use my guess at how the US does it, I'm a Brit ;)

Neither, though, would use 'a' in that situation, they'd use 'one'.

*From comments:*
If we are using "whole" numbers, such as 100, 1,000, 1,000,000 etc, then 'a' could be used. A thousand or a million is perfectly acceptable. It just tends not to be used when the number is more 'complex'.

Comment: The Americans just don't use "and" in numbers. Plenty of speakers of various dialects might use "a" in an informal spoken context, but certainly it wouldn't be correct in formal contexts or in writing.

Comment: @Darael - I, too, thought of a few exceptions to using "one" instead of "a" – although I think it's usually done with rounder numbers (like "a thousand") more so than with longer numbers (like, "a thousand eleven"). One example was printed by _The Economist_: "When such missiles cost a thousand dollars rather than a million, no target will be too cheap to engage." Then there's this dialogue from the film _The Game_:  Christine: "Your shoes cost a thousand dollars?" Nicholas: "That one did."

Comment: Yeah, "a" for round numbers is common even in writing. It's interstitial "a" that's speech-only.

Comment: Yes, I ought to add a bit about "whole numbers" which can use 'a'.

Comment: Regarding the American non-use of *and*: It's somewhat dialectical and a matter of individual style, but the rule for when you don't use *and* is just "never use and"; it isn't about certain numbers or anything.  We (USAnians) tend to regard *and* as making things more ambiguous: is "one hundred and ten" one number (110) or two separate numbers (100, and 10)?

Comment: @stangdon - The rule isn't quite "never use *and*."  The rule is, "only use *and* between the integer and fractional parts." The number 1232.1 in formal American English is "one thousand, two hundred thirty-two **and** one tenth."

Comment: @CanadianYankee - True, I wasn't considering fractional parts.  I should have said, "In integers..."

Answer (score 0):

"a thousand a hundred and ten" is *grammatical* but not *idiomatic* in written English. A native speaker would be likely to spend a moment confused, but would understand what you meant.

It is, however, idiomatic in some *spoken* dialects.

If you're going to use "a", use it *consistently*. Don't use "one" for some parts of the number and "a" for others.

Answer (score 0):

> **Could I say:**
>    - a thousand ten (1010)
>    - a thousand a hundred eleven(1111)
>
> or in these cases I must use one thousand instead of a thousand?

There are a couple of different issues here:

1. Your question is about the difference between saying **a** hundred/thousand or **one** thousand/thousand
2. But you appear to have missed out an "*and*" in your examples too, so we need to address that as well.

Firstly, as a general rule, you can use "a" instead of "one" when referring to hundreds, thousands, millions etc, **only if** there are no other units *greater than tens* that require counting.

> **Examples**
>   199 = One hundred and ninety nine
>   **or** A hundred and ninety nine
>   (both of these are acceptable)
>
> 1099 = One thousand and ninety nine
>   **or** A thousand and ninety nine
>   (both of these are acceptable)
>
> 1199 = One thousand, one hundred and ninety nine - **correct**
>   **but** A thousand, one hundred and ninety nine - **incorrect**

In that last example it is incorrect for the reason I detailed above - there were *hundreds* to count (one) and so you must also count the thousands (one).

---

Secondly, your example...

> 1010 = a thousand ten - **incorrect**

...is incorrect, **not** because of the "a", but because you are missing an "and". It should be:

> 1010 = a thousand **and** ten

So I'll address that:

**Tens**
Unlike some other languages, in English there is **no** use of "and" in numbers under 100.

> **Examples**
>   20 = twenty
>   21 = twenty one
>   90 = ninety
>   99 = ninety nine

**Hundreds**
Once you reach the hundreds, "and" goes in between the hundreds and the tens.

> **Examples**
>   100 = one hundred
>   110 = one hundred and ten
>   199 = one hundred and ninety nine

**Thousands and higher**
Once you reach the thousands, the rules above still apply.

You *can* say:

> A thousand
>   **OR**
>   One thousand

You can also say:

> **A** thousand and ninety nine

But if you have hundreds to count (or thousands, if you've reached a million) then you must number them:

> One thousand, one hundred.

If you have any tens, the "and" goes *before* the tens, *even if there are no hundreds*, like this:

> 1,000,099 = A million and ninety nine
>   1,100,099 = One million, one hundred thousand and ninety nine

Comment: I'm downvoting you because the use of **and** in counting is a purely British thing - in US English, it's not only much less common, but is often regarded as an error - and you make it sound like a universal rule.

Comment: @stangdon Ah that explains the classic AMERICAN movie "**One Hundred One Dalmatians**". I'm being sarcastic, obviously.